# Nginx doesn't allow callback urls in parameters

Tags: wordpress, nginx, woocommerce, nginx-config

I'm trying to connect Printful service to my Wordpress website and I getting 403 error. After some search I found out similar issue rised by Printful devs (https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/10678) and it seems like nginx settings on the host I have my website is too strict. It doesn't allow urls like this as it has url as a parameter: http://example.com/wc-auth/v1/login?test=http://google.com

I've reached out Printful devs and my hosting provider, but both of them don't know how to fix it. I don't want to change hosting provider, so looking for a solution.

Does anyone know what ninx settings are responsible for urls as parameters being blocked?

Comment: Is this not something that you can URL encode before sending to your server? `http://example.com/wc-auth/v1/login?test=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2F` and then decode as needed? Generally it's unwise to pass URL parameters that aren't properly encoded

Comment: @Xhynk, the issue is that is Printful plugin that should do it or Woocommence. I don't have control over it therefore I can't encode it and certanly can't decode it as it lands on their servers.
Similar solution was proposed in the link above but it still happens to me. So I thought to find nginx setting.

Comment: What does your nginx.conf look like?